# ES6 await is a reserved word

Tags: ecmascript-2017

I have the sample code like this:

```
import net from 'net'
import B from 'bluebird'

class Test {
    constructor() {}
    async start() {
        return await new B((resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                this.socketClient = net.connect(4724);
                // Windows: the socket errors out when ADB restarts. Let's catch it to avoid crashing.
                this.socketClient.on('error', (err) => {
                    if (!this.ignoreUnexpectedShutdown) {
                        throw new Error(`Android bootstrap socket crashed: ${err}`);
                    }
                });
                this.socketClient.once('connect', () => {
                    log.info("Android testbundle socket is now connected");
                    resolve();
                });
            } catch (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
        })
    }
}
let t = new Test()
await t.start()
```

But when i transform into es5 code, I got this error:

```
SyntaxError: src/test.js: await is a reserved word (34:0)
  32 |
  33 | let t = new Test()
> 34 | await t.start()
```

I know await should be corresponding to async, but start() method is marked as async, still got error.
How to solve it?

Comment: You should really decide if you want to use semicolons, or not.

Comment: `await` can only be used inside `async` functions in the first place.

Comment: If this is the entire file, you can simply delete every `async` and `await` and your code will work fine.